# How to group contents in an array of dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, sorting

I know this could have been solved easily from backend but was curious to know if there is any efficient way to solve this issue from front end using js.

I have an array

```
[
 {  
    id: 11
    ruleDesc: "rule 1 "
 },
{  
    id: 15
    ruleDesc: "rule 2 "
 },
{  
    id: 12
    ruleDesc: "rule 3 "
 },
{  
    id: 11
    ruleDesc: "rule 4 "
 },
{  
    id: 11
    ruleDesc: "rule 5 "
 },

]
```

What I'm expecting is

```
[
  {  
        id: 11
        ruleDesc: "rule 1 "
        ruleDesc: "rule 4 "
        ruleDesc: "rule 5 "
     },
{  
        id: 12
        ruleDesc: "rule 3 "
     },
{  
        id: 15
        ruleDesc: "rule 2 "
     },
]
```

Comment: In you expected output the first object contain duplicate keys. The last one will overwrite all.

Comment: Object keys are unique but your expected structure has the same key multiple times.

Comment: objects cannot have repeated properties, if you want to has multiple `ruleDesc` within a single object you need to use an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects)

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of `ruleDesc` for same group. Because an object can't have same keys.

You can use `reduce()` to get an object and then use `Object.values` to get an array.

```js
const arr = [ { id: 11, ruleDesc: "rule 1 " }, { id: 15, ruleDesc: "rule 2 " }, { id: 12, ruleDesc: "rule 3 " }, { id: 11, ruleDesc: "rule 4 " }, { id: 11, ruleDesc: "rule 5 " } ]

const res = arr.reduce((ac,{id,ruleDesc}) => {
  ac[id] = ac[id] || {id,ruleDesc:[]}
  ac[id].ruleDesc.push(ruleDesc);
  return ac;
},{})
console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the answer from Masheer Ali, but I think the reduction is a little nicer:

```js
const transform = arr => Object .values (arr .reduce ((a, {id, ruleDesc}) => 
  ({...a, [id]: {id, ruleDesc: [...( (a [id] || {}) .ruleDesc || [] ), ruleDesc]}}),
  {}
))

const rules = [{id: 11, ruleDesc: "rule 1 "}, {id: 15, ruleDesc: "rule 2 "}, {id: 12, ruleDesc: "rule 3 "}, {id: 11, ruleDesc: "rule 4 "}, {id: 11, ruleDesc: "rule 5 "}]

console .log (
  transform (rules)
)
```

One advantage is that if you have additional properties you want to merge, it's only a minor tweak:

```js
const transform = arr => Object .values (arr .reduce ((a, {id, ruleDesc, ...rest}) => 
  ({...a, [id]: {...(a[id] || {}), id,  ruleDesc: [...((a[id] || {}).ruleDesc || []) , ruleDesc], ...rest}}),
  {}
))
```